# How to create a new Git repo instead of an old one and keep the commits history?

Tags: git

Suppose I have a Git repo and it has a name — `old_repo` — and a remote origin `old_remote`.

Now, I want to create a new repo with a name — `new_repo` – and I want to change its remote origin to the brand new `new_remote`.

I also want to make it possible to update the `new_repo` if there are any updates to the `old_repo` (but not the other way round), but I don't want the `new_repo` to be a fork of the `old_repo`.

What would be the best way to do that?

I'm thinking about this:

```
mkdir /path/to/new_repo
cd /path/to/new_repo
git --bare init

// the new_repo it's accessible via ssh://my_host/new_remote
// now I want the branch master to be accessible as the branch master in the new one

cd /path/to/old_repo
git push ssh://my_host/new_repo +master:master

cd /path/to/new_repo
git clone ssh://my_host/new_repo
```

However, in the case above, how would I be able to get updates from the `old_repo` into the `new_repo` if needed?

Comment: Note that a Git repository is self-contained, and the commits *are* the history. The history is the set of commits you have. That's in some ways all there is to it. When you `git fetch` from your repo to get commits from another repo, or `git push` to send commits from your repo to another repo, you get or send commits, and that's all there is to that either.

Comment: Everything else (and there is **a lot** of "everything else") is in service of using and adding-to the set of commits. But it's the commits that matter. The rest of a repository is just supporting stuff *for* the commits. Cloning a repository copies all the other repository's commits (and none of its branches, because branches don't matter, only commits matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would set old_repo as an upstream, and then you could pull from it:

```
git remote add upstream /path/to/old/repo
```

Then, to get updates from the old repository, you can pull from upstream:

```
git pull upstream
```

Side note: Instead of doing all that stuff with cloning old repo, you could just copy it to a new location and then change the origin:

```
cp /path/to/old/repo /path/to/new/repo
cd /path/to/new/repo
git remote set origin <new remote location>
git remote add upstream <old remote location>
```

Then, whenever you need to fetch updates you can just run `git pull upstream` (or `git fetch upstream` if you want to inspect them before merging)